# How to repeat a background diagonally (only 1 time per line)

Tags: css

I want to repeat a background in diagonal direction, not vertical or horizontal.Do you know a way for that? For example I want a chain that starts from the upper left to repeat itself diagonally to the lower right.I was thinking for some background repeat solution with multiple images, one overlaying in a usefull way the other background(cicada method), but did not succed.Let me know, if you know a solution for this.

Comment: After reading your answers, I think I need to be more clear about this:http://i47.tinypic.com/2uh1pgi.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `:before` rule containing your background-image in a rotated way, and transform it:

```
.foo:before {
    display: block;
    background: url("myimage") repeat-x;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin:  left center;
    -moz-transform-origin:  left center;
    -webkit-transform-origin:  left center;
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
}

.foo {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r8BzE/

Comment: mkprogramming provided the *exact same* answer. And also explained multiple other approaches. The reason I didn't provide css transformation as an answer is that it's not cross-platform, and from my experience, you're always forced to revert to boring old technologies when developing something you're paid for. Sadly.

Comment: Adding to last sentence: unless you do your coolest top-notch bleeding-edge technology server-side (that's what I've resorted to :P).

Comment: It's not the exact same answer, it differs in `repeat-y`

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way possible (you will save a lot of time) is to create a big enough (say, 500x500) png image that contains the diagonal background. If you can, make a gif and it will not be big in file size.

A second solution is to generate multiple divs.

Say, you have a 50x50 png image that you want to duplicate diagonally as a background of a 500x500 div.

Make 10 horizontal divs, each 50px (10%) high, and give each consecutive div +50 background-position-x.

```
#div1{
    background:transparent url(my_bg.png) 0px top repeat-y;
}
#div2{
    background:transparent url(my_bg.png) 50px top repeat-y;
}
#div3{
    background:transparent url(my_bg.png) 100px top repeat-y;
}
```

etc. You can also generate this css with php or any server-side language you're using.

Example PHP code:

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo "#div$i{ background:transparent url(my_bg.png) ".(50*$i)."px top repeat-y; }";
}
?>
</style>
```

But it's just not possible with plain css to achieve diagonal background with a single div.

Comment: Yes, the incrementing is a good solution, though I'm looking for a plain css solution(to bad calc() is not supported or counter-increment can not be used like this)

Comment: JavaScript would be also possible to generate the DIVs + you could calculate the viewport width and the amount of DIVs which are needed to fill the full/required width.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get something like this to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/johnkpaul/8LmgF/

http://johnkpaul.tumblr.com/post/17057209155/wish-background-repeat-had-a-repeat-diagonal-option

The code looks something like this:

```
.original-background{    
   background:url(http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2400/rowofstars.gif) repeat;
}

.diagonal-background:before{
  content:"";
  background:url(http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2400/rowofstars.gif) repeat;
  width:200%;
  height:200%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:-1;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-13deg) translate(10px,-220px); 
  -moz-transform:rotate(-13deg) translate(10px,-220px); 
  -o-transform:rotate(-13deg) translate(10px,-220px); 
  -ms-transform:rotate(-13deg) translate(10px,-220px); 
}

.diagonal-background{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

But it might just be easier to make a background image. Here are a few resources to try:

- http://www.stripegenerator.com/
- http://bgpatterns.com/

Comment: Your answer linked to this same question, removed it.

Comment: Great. The part about diagonal background is (sadly) not cross-browser. Many people have outdated browsers including outdated versions of Firefox and Opera, and of course, IE.

Comment: Yeah it's sad, but a potential solution.

Comment: Right. I'm always supporting new technologies on the web, but whether you use it or not depends what you are developing. Most companies won't accept a web-site or a web-app if it doesn't work on at least recent versions of IE. I don't like IE, but it's a fact.

Comment: Ok, so I want to work with multiple background images: background-image:url(pic1.png),url(pic2.png),url(pic3.png);  background-position:0 0,20px 20px,40px 40px;  background-repeat:no-repeat                                the problem is, I can't do this to the infinite, I need to find a looping tehnic or cicada principle implementation in all this

Comment: At least for IE support there is the filter matrix solution to rotate elements.